# Accessing dictionary keys using defaults

Tags: defaults

How do I use defaults to access a specific field in a dictionary? I've tried doing this

```
$ defaults read -app Terminal "Window Settings.Pro"
```

but it doesn't work. Accessing `"Window Settings"` on its own does work though, and `Pro` is a key in that dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaults` isn't capable of doing this.

One of the options you have is `plistbuddy` :

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print 'Window Settings':Pro" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

Comment: Is there a way to "refresh" the terminal after making a change? Because it doesn't seem to be committed. Reading the value shows it has changed, but the terminal doesn't reflect that change, and opening its settings also shows the old value.